# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'. plt.plot

Tags: python

When I write the following code, I get the following error.
What am I doing wrong??

```
def f(t):
    return np.sin(t**2)

n = 20  # number of points for Riemann integration
a = 0; b = 2
P = np.linspace(a, b, n)  # Standard partition constant width
dt = (b-a)/n
T = [np.random.rand()*dt + p for p in P[:-1]]  # Randomly chosen point
```

## Doing a few more things and then:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

plt.plot(T, f(T), '.', markersize=10)
plt.bar(P[:-1], f(T), width=dt, alpha=0.2, align='edge')

x = np.linspace(a, b, n*100)  # we take finer spacing to get a "smooth" graph
y = f(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title('Riemann sum with n = {} points'.format(n))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Finally I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "riman.py", line 35, in <module>
    plt.plot(T, f(T), '.', markersize=10)
    File "riman.py", line 11, in f
    return np.sin(t**2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: `t` is a list...

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory – the power operator `**` is not defined for the built-in `list` type.

They *are* however defined for `np.array`s:

```
>>> np.array(range(5))**2
array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16])
```

Fix:

```
T = np.array([np.random.rand()*dt + p for p in P[:-1]])
```

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: @BatelCarmona click on the gray tick on the left, just below the score